# BibTeX : skip$ vs. 'skip$

Tags: bibtex

Looking through few bst files (BibTeX styles) I noted that `skip$` built-in function is sometimes referred to as `'skip$` (i.e. by name) and sometimes as `skip$` (i.e. by value). I think I understand the construct such as

```
"string value" 'foo :=
```

which means that the function `foo` gets the value "string value" but I don't understand what is the difference between `'skip$` and `skip$`? Can one explain that issue. And how `'pop$` does differ from `pop$`?

For example `plainnat.bst` from natbib package has the following chunck of code:

```
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
```

Second pair of examples is borrowed from aipauth4-1.bst (revtex package):

```
FUNCTION {date.block}
{
  new.block.comma
  skip$
}
```

but

```
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can explain what you need to do: the reasoning is something different!

You need to keep an eye on the braces here. For example

```
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
```

could also be written as

```
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ }
    { output.nonnull }
  if$
}
```

The key thing to notice here is the `if$` statement. That requires that it preceded by an integer and two 'functions'. If you use something like

```
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    pop$
    output.nonnull
  if$
}
```

BibTeX will try to execute the functions incorrectly, and errors will come up. So for the two branches of a conditional, you need either

- The branch in braces or
- A single non-braced statement quoted as it's name using `'`.